# Laravel Gate method not being called

Tags: laravel, authorization

In my Laravel 5.4 application users can create Projects and then Posts inside those projects.

I'm trying to prevent users from creating or editing posts inside a project they don't have access to.
To do this I implemented a Gate as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates
The gate checks if a user is the owner of the project.

```
Gate::define('create-post', function ($user, $project) {
    Log::info($project) // !!! Never gets called
    return $project->owner_id == $user->id;
});
```

On the PostController I call Gate::denies passing the project as an argument

```
if (Gate::denies('create-post', $project)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

The problem is the code I defined for the gate never gets called. Instead it always returns false and goes to the 403 error.
However, the code does get called if I don't pass the project as an argument but that makes it useless.

I also want to add that in this case I cannot use a Policy because the create method only takes one argument ($user) and if I try to pass the $project it fails the same way it does with the Gate.

Is this a bug? Is there another, better way to implement this funcionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using a policy. I created the following method in ProjectPolicy:

```
public function createOrEditPosts(User $user, Project $project)
{
    return $project->owner_id == $user->id;
}
```

Then from PostController I call:

```
$this->authorize('createOrEditPosts', $project));
```

I still don't know why the gate approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. It seems something wrong happens when the second parameter in Gate::allows() is an eloquent model.

If you pass in denies() any other variable (even object, but not eloquent model), your Log::info() will work. 
I wasted the whole day with it and switched to $user->can()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I replaced `Gate::denies()` with `Gate::allows()`.
I'm not sure why but this worked for me. The policy framework is a little bit tricky to be honest

Answer (score 0):

first, check to log in to your project then gate work because of the gate when work that you log in to your project.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: yes I know and I agree with you but this hint is just hint and haven't any code to solve. because sometimes we forget to log in and after check gate allow function and laravel don't know what kind of user is in the site so `gate::alow` don't work.